# Extra unexpected part when converting from Object to JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have an Object, and when I use the object mapper to convert from object to String and return it. Besides the properties in this object, I found an extra key displayed. For example

```
public class Person(){

private int age;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

setter and getter for those properties above,


public String getFullName(){

return this.firstName + this.lastName;
}



}
```

Why, the JONS I get for this person class includes a key called FullName ?  Why can I get ride of that ? is that because Java found the getter for the fullName and automatically consider the FullName is a property so that when I convert from Person object to JSON, it add it ?

Comment: Which mapper are you using? Jackson? The thing is that the serializer it's using your getters and setters, and because of that is mapping that method.

Comment: @facundofarias I used the ObjectMapper  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the ObjectMapper also look into the getter to serialize it, so if you only want to serialize the fields, then you can create mapper object like blow

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();                                                
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

Or, there is another way to do it, you can specify annotation it in the class you want to serialize. Add the following annotation before the class

```
  @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Jackson will normally serialize all getter methods on the provided POJO (unless configured otherwise). To ignore serialization of the `fullName` property simply add `@JsonIgnore` on the getter-method:

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getFullName() {
    return this.firstName + this.lastName;
}
```

From the [JavaDocs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/index.html):

> Marker annotation that indicates that the annotated method or field is to be ignored by introspection-based serialization and deserialization functionality. That is, it should not be consider a "getter", "setter" or "creator".

So, basically what this means is the all methods or fields marked with `@JsonIgnore` will be ignored for serialization and deserialization.